# Group Neighbors by Outgoing Edge Type and Add Self to Result List

Tags: aggregate, gremlin, gremlinnet

I want a result like this:

```
[
 {
  "vertex": [ the_vertex_itself ]
 },
 {
  "outgoingEdgeGroup1": [ list_of_outgoing_neighbors_with_edge_type_outgoingEdgeGroup1 ]
 },
 {
  "outgoingEdgeGroup2": [ list_of_outgoing_neighbors_with_edge_type_outgoingEdgeGroup2 ]
 }
]
```

I'm able to get this:

```
[
 {
  "outgoingEdgeGroup1": [ list_of_outgoing_neighbors_with_edge_type_outgoingEdgeGroup1 ]
 },
 {
  "outgoingEdgeGroup2": [ list_of_outgoing_neighbors_with_edge_type_outgoingEdgeGroup2 ]
 }
]
```

With the following query:

```
g.V('{unitId}').outE().group().by(label()).by(inV().fold())
```

But how would I append on the target vertex itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is just to use a `union`. If you need a more complete key/value type of structure that can be created also by adding `project` steps or nested `group` steps.

Using the air-routes data set:

```java
gremlin> g.V(44).union(identity().values('city'),inE().group().by(label()).by(outV().fold())).fold()

==>[Santa Fe,[contains:[v[3742],v[3728]],route:[v[13],v[31],v[20],v[8]]]]
```

Comment: Perfect! My final query (I noticed a typo in my post) ends up as `g.V('{unitId}').union(identity(),outE().group().by(label()).by(inV().fold()))` Not quite the exact format I desired but it will suffice.